# Can code occurences found by Alt + F7 in Idea be grouped by git user

Tags: git, intellij-idea

`Alt + F7` is the shortcut key that I mostly use in Idea. And it is very efficient and convenient when searching for code blocks that are referenced by a certain class, method, or field.

However, assuming the case:

```
Backpack backpack = new Backpack(role);
backpack.increase(config.reward());
backpack.commitToMail(role, 1001); // 1001 is the mail id
```

If I want to find all the occurence of `commitToMail` written by me and add a judgement before `commitToMail` line to avoid sending an empty mail to player, I'll press `Alt + F7` but Idea also show me other member's occurence in the project besides mine.

```
Backpack backpack = new Backpack(role);
backpack.increase(config.reward());
if (backpack.getStash().isEmpty()) {
    return;
}
backpack.commitToMail(role, 1001);
```

Thus I have to check each of them to avoid modifying other member's code. This is really a very troublesome and trivial process.

So if is there any method(plugin support?) to group the occurences by git user. All I currently see are the following options:
[image]